# How to keep focus with input field when value is invalid

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery. I am learning by using the demo illustrated in the example

http://www.geektantra.com/projects/jquery-form-validate/advanced_demo/

What changes should be made so that the focus remains in the input field which is not yet validated.....i.e if an I/P field is not correct,then the focus should remain on that field and user should not be able to move to next field until he enters the field in question correct.

Comment: FWIW: It's generally not good practice to trap users in fields. Instead, give them an indication that a field is incomplete or invalid (an error next to it, red outline, etc., etc.), but let them move around as they see fit. Only *prevent* actions when necessary (for instance, if they try to confirm the information they've supplied and move forward). Trapping users in fields is poor user experience design.

Answer (score 0):

T.J. Crowder has it right.

None the less this might be what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/focus/